# Use a stack to reverse the words of a sentence. Keep reading in words and adding them to the stack until you have a word that ends in a period

Tags: java, stack, reverse, capitalization

This is the assignment my professor assigned:

> Use a stack to reverse the words of a sentence. Keep reading in words and adding them to the stack until you have a word that ends in a period.  When that happens, pop the words off the stack and print them.  For example, for the input "It was a period of civil war." you should output "War civil of period a was it."  Pay attention to the capitalization and punctuation changes.

I have the program so far reversing the order of the words but I don't know how to have it stop at the period, change the capitalization, and move the punctuation. How do I do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReverseWordsInString 
{
  //main method
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("1. Enter string to reverse : ");
    String inputString = scanner.nextLine();

    if (inputString == null || inputString.length() == 0) 
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the valid string");
      return;
    }
    String reverse = reverseStringWordWise_Stack(inputString);
    System.out.printf("\n3. Reverse string using stack is : %s", reverse);
  } 
  //reverses the string using a stack
  private static String reverseStringWordWise_Stack(String inputString) 
   {
     String[] arrString = inputString.trim().split(Pattern.quote(" "));
     Stack stack = new Stack();
     for(String input : arrString) 
     {
       stack.push(input);
     }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while( !stack.isEmpty()) 
    {
      builder.append(stack.pop()).append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can handle the case in such way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrString.length; i++) {
    // first one to lower case
    if (i == 0) {
        String str = arrString[i].substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + arrString[i].substring(1);
        stack.push(str);
    }
    // last one to Upper case and trim period
    else if (i == arrString.length - 1) {
        String str = arrString[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + arrString[i].substring(1);
        // trim period
        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        stack.push(str);
    } else {
        stack.push(arrString[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes:

1. Break out of loop if the token ends with a period chatacter and strip out period character before pushing it into `stack`, e.g.:

   `for(String input : arrString) {
      if(input.endsWith("."){
         stack.push(input.toLowerCase().substring(0, input.length() - 1));
         break;
      }else{
         stack.push(input);
      }
   }`
2. Decapitalise the last word while popping from stack:

   `while( !stack.isEmpty()) {
       if(stack.size() == 1){
           String element = stack.pop().toString();
           builder.append(element.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + 
             element.substring(1)).append(" ");
       }else{
           builder.append(stack.pop()).append(" ");
       }
   }`
3. Capitalise first letter of resultant string and append period:

   `builder.append(".");
   String result = builder.toString();
   return result.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.substring(1);`

Comment: For step 2 on the line "String element = stack.pop();" I keep getting a type mismatch error. please help

Comment: @Hogwartsishome change it to `stack.pop().toString()`, I have updated the answer.